# Использование Setup Wizard

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Для создания инсталляционного пакета решил использовать Setup Wizard. Мое Windows приложение создано на базе .Net Framework 2.0. Я добавляю проект Setup Wizard и почему-то по умолчанию Launch Conditions устанавливается .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Я меняю его на .Net Framework 2.0. Потом компилирую созданный проект. И вот при нажатии созданного файла Setup, выходит предложение установить .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, который он хочет загрузить из интернета, если жмешь отмену, то установка приложения прекращается.

До этого я тоже создавал проекты Setup Wizard, но все было нормально. Сейчас я вообще не понимаю, почему он требует установку пакета .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Comment: Так может он просто предлагает ставить всегда посленюю доступную версию, а не ту, которая использовалась при создании приложения?

Comment: Возможно оно так и есть, просто не могу понять как это можно исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, оказывается кроме launch conditions нужно поменять еще и prerequisites. Project/Properties для Setup Project, закладка Build, кнопка Prerequisites.